# How to debug "Object doesn't support this property or method" in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting error '483': Object doesn't support this property or method on he highlighted line. I'm a complete beginner with excel-vba and I am trying to learn it by myself.

```
Sub Magic()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim featcode(9999)
Dim partnum(9999)
k = 4
i = 0
j = 0        
For i = 2 To 616 
    featcode(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
    For j = 1 To 9999 
    partnum(j) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(j, 8).Value
Next j
        For i = 2 To 616
    For j = 1 To 1000
        If featcode(i) = partnum(j) Then
            **ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, k).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).partnum(j).Value**
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next j
    k = 4
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Since `partNum(j)` is going to be a value, you can't do `.Value.Value`.  What is `partNum(j)`? Is that a value for a row, or column? You're missing what `Cell()` you want to put `partNum(j)` in, if that was your intention. Can you explain what the sub is supposed to do?

Comment: Try replacing the line to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, k).Value = partnum(j)` . That's why you have the array in the first place, no ?

Comment: Just use `..= partnum(j)` you dont need the reference to the Worksheet

Comment: Hi and thanks for helping. partNum(j) is supposed to store values down a column. What this vba is trying to do is the following: I have a long list of characteristics and a lot of part numbers on another worksheet that have some characteristics of their own. There are multiple characteristics for each part number and they are not unique. I need to extract all the part numbers for a certain set of characteristics. I know I'll need to use a 2D array but this was just the draft to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exclusively an answer to your question, I wanted to als give you some tips regarding your code

```
Sub Magic()

Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
'You can use dynamic arrays in VBA so you dont have to "guess" the length beforehand, see first comment to this answer
Dim featcode(9999)
Dim partnum(9999)
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
'you dont have to assign values to these variables outside of your for loop, as you assign them right there
k = 4
i = 0
j = 0        
For i = 2 To 616 
    featcode(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
'indent new lines properly, so you don't lose overview
For j = 1 To 9999 
    partnum(j) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(j, 8).Value
Next j
For i = 2 To 616
   For j = 1 To 1000
        If featcode(i) = partnum(j) Then
            'you can declare objects for referencing to worksheets or cells, so you dont have to write these enormous blocks of code (see above)
            'so instead of ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, k).Value = partnum(j)
            'use
            ws.Cells(i,k) = partnum(j)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next
    k = 4
Next
End Sub
```

HTH :)